# XPath not returning results on Google App Engine for PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, xpath, google-app-engine-php

I'm having an issue using XPath on the Google App Engine for PHP.

So I have the following code:

```
function getDataXpath($url_str, $xpath_exp_str)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url_str);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query("".$xpath_exp_str."");

    if (!is_null($elements)) {
        return $elements;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then I simply run it like this to get the nodes:

```
getDataXpath($url_str, $xpath_exp_str);
```

So on my local PHP install (v 5.5.19), when I run the following:

```
$url_str = 'http://www.alexa.com/topsites/category;0/Top/Shopping';
$xpath_exp_str = "//ul/li[@class='site-listing']/div/p/a";
$xpath_data = getDataXpath($url_str, $xpath_exp_str);
print_r($xpath_data);
```

I get the following result:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 25 );
```

and this is correct.

However, when I run the same code on Google App Engine for PHP (v 5.5.26), I get the following:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 );
```

Has anyone had this issue, and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that Amazon might be blocking programmatic access to the Alexa TopSites pages. I'm actually subscribed to their [new API](http://aws.amazon.com/alexa-top-sites/), but it doesn't allow you to categorize responses (e.g. top e-commerce sites) like you can on the website, which is why I'm resorting to XPath.

I tried the same script on some other URLs and I didn't have any issues.

Anyway, it works when I run it locally (in browser and command-line), so I'll just have to skip Google App Engine for now. It's a broken workflow, especially since this was part of a much bigger automation effort, but it's out of my hands at this point.

Comment: Hey, I do Community Support for the Google Cloud Platform and I'd like to let you know that something like this would make a great post to the [Public Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/list). Just post a small snippet of code required to get this issue to manifest itself, we'll reproduce it and see what we can do.

Comment: Hey @Nick, thanks for the feedback. On further review, I don't think this is Google App Engine's fault; I only had this issue with Alexa Top Sites, so it's possible they could be blocking the appspot.com domain as part of an overall web-scraping prevention setup. Cheers.